# What's the field single_step mean in java.lang.Thread?

Tags: java

I saw this field in Java 7.

```
 /* Whether or not to single_step this thread. */
private boolean     single_step;
```

I just don't understand what does "single_step this thread" mean.

Comment: It turns out that this field is not directly used (at least not by direct reference).

Comment: Ye, but it may be used by reflection or something, I doubt they would put useless fields there.

Answer (score 2):

As of [JDK-8193818](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193818):

> This field dates back to JDK 1.0/1.1 and the Classic VM. Not used by the HotSpot VM.

This issue is closed, field is removed since java 11.

Answer (score 0):

As per `jdk1.0` refrence the field `single_step` defined like -

```
/* Whether or not to single_step this thread. */
private boolean single_step;
```

after search I found:

**The field single_step was used by classical VM for enabling or disabling single step on running thread. But this is not in used with HotSpot virtual machines and removed from jdk library.**

You can check the [reference of jdk1.0](http://web.mit.edu/java/java_v1.1.6/distrib/sun4x_57/src/java/lang/Thread.java) and [fixes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193818?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) here.